# jQuery to hide columns in a view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I am using SharePoint 2013 on Office 365

I have a list called Client View, that is grouped by client, then by password type, I would like to hide columns that do not contain any info, so for example Hostname does not contain anything so I would like to hide it in the view

I have also changed the default list style to the boxed style

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by removing the columns you don't want in the View, you don't need jQuery to do this.

Read this Office help article on modifying Views in Lists and Libraries: Joiners Movers and Leavers

Comment: I need this column in the view for other password types, some password types do not require a hostname, if I remove it from the view it will be gone for all the other password types

For example I have a password type of Domain Admin, this obviously does not need a hostname but a NAS would

Comment: In that case I would use JSLink (http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013) you have control over the logic that renders the output of each time. You might have to manually rebuild your layout as the boxed style, but at least you can do something with the fields depending on the values of other fields.

Comment: JSLink is absolutely awesome, btw, if you havent' used it before, have some JavaScript knowledge and despise XSLT from previous versions of SharePoint, then JSLink is the best thing ever.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that article talks about adding icons for priority, I've used Jquery code in a CEWP before to do similar things, do you know what I could use?

Comment: You can still use this technology (JSLink) to render exact what each row will output. You can then test the values of other fields in the row (such as the password type) and decide how to render the password, if at all.

Comment: Hey James, the problem is I do not know how to write javascript

Comment: Can anyone else help me out the jQuery to hide columns in the boxed style within a list?